# how to install id3 library in Centos?

Tags: php, id3

I need to install this library..

Here is the link http://getid3.sourceforge.net

How to install in my Centos server ? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I just installed id3 on my Centos 6 AWS instance:

Change directory:
cd /tmp

Get rpm package:
wget http://pkgrepo.linuxtech.net/el6/release/x86_64/id3-0.78-5.el6.x86_64.rpm

Install package:
sudo rpm -i id3-0.78-5.el6.x86_64.rpm

I received an warning [warning: id3-0.78-5.el6.x86_64.rpm: Header V4 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 5cc6587f: NOKEY] indicating I don't have the package signature key, which is used to verify the source. Since the package is coming from the CentOS rpm site I'm good with that but, to verify the authenticity of the package to ensure it hasn't been corrupted I ran this:
rpm -K --nosignature id3-0.78-5.el6.x86_64.rpm

Sources:
https://centos.pkgs.org/6/linuxtech/id3-0.78-5.el6.x86_64.rpm.html
https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-check-rpm-sig.html